# NSDateFormatter for decrypted string

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, aes, encryption, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to get a encrypted date from a web server and convert it into NSDate object. But the date formatter always returns nil date. The decrypted string does not work with the date formatter, but typing a straight date string works.

How do I debug this problem and get date formatter to parse my date?

```
// Decrypt the message
NSData *encrypted = [NSData dataFromBase64String:dataReturned];
NSData *decrypted = [encrypted AES128DecryptWithKey:key];
NSString *decryptedString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:decrypted encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
// decryptedString is @"2011-04-02" according to GDB

//  NSString *decryptedString = @"2011-04-02"; //This works
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];    
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease];
[formatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *expiryDate = [formatter dateFromString:[decryptedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                                [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
```

Comment: This may be totally wrong, but I have a sneaking suspicion something is going on with that trim statement that is messing with this.  Have you tried it without the trim statement? Or, if nothing else, pull the trim into a separate line and inspect the result before passing it to the formatter?

Comment: I actually tried initially without the trim and it didn't work. I added the trim cause I thought that's the problem but it didn't work either. I sort of just left the trim there afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if it works when you hardcode "2011-04-02" and it doesn't work when you think you've decrypted "2011-04-02" then obviously there's some difference between those two strings.

How about parsing and comparing both strings in code, to try and find what the difference is.

For example:

```
decryptedString = [decryptedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSString* goodString = @"2011-04-02";

NSLog(@"Decrypted String: %@", decryptedString);
NSLog(@"Good String: %@", goodString);
NSLog(@"Compare: %d" [goodString compare:decryptedString]);  // 0 means they're identical.

NSDate* expiryDate = [formatter dateFromString:decryptedString];
NSDate* goodDate = [formatter dateFromString:goodString];

NSLog(@"Decrypted Date: %@", expiryDate);
NSLog(@"Good Date: %@", goodDate);
```

Run the code and look at the console output.  Hopefully the problem will be a little clearer.

Comment: Decrypted String: 2011-04-02
Good String: 2011-04-02
Compare: -1
Decrypted Date: (null)
Good Date: 2011-04-01 22:00:00 +0000

Comment: I don't know how to find the difference between the good string and decrypted string though.

Comment: -1 means the strings are different.  Do you see any difference when both of those strings are printed to the console?  If need be, do a character by character comparison.  Perhaps there's a leading NULL or control character in your decrypted string.

Comment: My first comment is the console printout. My human eye sees no difference, maybe it's different underlying?

Comment: Do a character-by-character comparison, using the -characterAtIndex: method.

Comment: or just compare `length`or print bytes by converting to NSData or getting a char * array

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why the decrypted string have length of 16, whereas the good string have length of 10.

I managed to fix it by removing the control characters.

`decryptedString = [decryptedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet controlCharacterSet]];`